# Is defining a property & synthesize for a variable in a singleton class allowed?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, singleton

Defining a property & synthesize for a variable in a singleton class allowed?,like below
in interface,

```
@property(nonatomic,assign)NSInteger value;
```

and in implementation file,

```
@synthesize value;
```

or we just have to declare a variable like below,

```
@interface SingletonDataClass : NSObject
{
    NSInteger value;
}
```

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything that you can do with your regular classes you can do with singletons.

There is no language concept called "singleton", it is just a common usage pattern of regular Objective C classes. What makes a class a singleton is the way you ensure its instantiation happens only once, i.e. your own supporting code.